On Kaluza's auxiliary electromagnetic field
Referring to Kaluza's 1921 paper that starts with the 5d ansatz $$\tilde{g}_{mn} = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
  g_{\mu\nu} & 2\alpha A_\mu \\
  2\alpha A_\nu & 2\mathfrak{g}
\end{array} \right)\space\space ;\alpha =const, \space\mathfrak{g}\space  a\space scalar\space field, 
$$
he calculates the components of the 5d connection, one of which is $$\tilde{\Gamma}_{4 \kappa \lambda} = \alpha \Sigma_{\kappa \lambda},$$
where $$\Sigma_{\kappa \lambda}=A_{κ,λ}+A_{λ,κ}$$ and which he refers to as the auxiliary electromagnetic field.
Later, as he computes the components of the 5d Riemann tensor under the approximation $\tilde{g}_{rs} \approx \tilde{\eta}_{rs}$ and the gauge $|Det(\tilde{g}_{rs})|=1$, he claims that the auxiliary field does not appear in the results.
This is somewhat baffling to me, because when I calculate the Ricci component under the same conditions, e.g. $$\tilde{R}_{\kappa\nu}=\tilde{R}^r_{\space\kappa\nu r}=-\frac{\partial\tilde{\Gamma}^r_{\space \kappa \nu}}{\partial x^r} + \tilde{\Gamma}^r_{\space \kappa l}\tilde{\Gamma}^l_{\space \nu r},$$
the partial derivative component in the summation over $r$ vanishes for $r=4$ due to the cylinder condition. But in the quadratic term, the component $\tilde{\Gamma}^4_{\space \kappa \lambda}\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\space \nu 4}$ persists. $\tilde{\Gamma}^4_{\space \kappa \lambda}$ under the conditions $\tilde{g}_{rs} \approx \tilde{\eta}_{rs}$ is the auxiliary field as above. It does not seem to become redundant, contrary to what has been claimed in the theory.
Due to this, the 5d vacuum gravitational equations $\tilde{R}_{\kappa \nu}=0$ seem to create an unexplained constraint on the electromagnetic potential $A_\mu$.
What am I missing? Or are you getting the same result? Grateful for answers!
(Note: this question uses modern notation for the Christoffels. Kaluza's notation is different. Further, his 5th dimension index is  $0$, whereas our's is $4$.)

No, it is a plus.
